# Register to be created from factory

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, dryioc

I'm trying to use DryIOC to resolve a scoped entity framework context. While this registration works, it feels weird:

```
container.Register<MyDbContext>( Reuse.ScopedTo<IMarkerInterface>(), Made.Of(() => Arg.Of<IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>>().CreateDbContext()) );
```

Especially, `Arg.Of` seems to be intended to be used differently. Is there a better way to write the `Made` part?

I can easily register a factory for `MyDbContext` with the (Microsoft-DI-) `ServiceCollection` with `AddDbContextFactory()`, so I do that. Then I create the DryIOC container the rest of my application uses from the `ServiceCollection` with using the `DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` extension.

In the DryIOC world now, I want a scoped `MyDbContext`. So I register the `MyDbContext` using `ScopedTo`, but I want each context instance to be produced by the previously registered (in the `ServiceCollection` world) factory. So, DryIOC's supposed to to resolve a factory, call create and put the result in the current scope, each time a `MyDbContext` is injected.

EDIT: I've upgraded to

```
container.Register<MyDbContext>( Reuse.ScopedTo<IMarkerInterface>(), Made.Of(container.Resolve<IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>>(), factory => factory.CreateDbContext()) );
```

which is still smelly because the `Resolve` is unnecessary early, but feels a bit better in total.

```
container.Register<MyDbContext>( Reuse.ScopedTo<IMarkerInterface>(), Made.Of(() => container.Resolve<IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>>(), factory => factory.CreateDbContext()) );
```

would be perfect, I guess, but doesn't work (at least with this syntax).

Comment: This code from is wrong on multiple levels. Could you provide more context on what you want to achieve?

Comment: @dadhi do you need more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you need something like this:

```cs
container.RegisterDelegate<IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>, MyDbContext>(
    factory => factory.CreateDbContext(),
    Reuse.ScopedTo<IMarkerInterface>());
```